# Keras multi-output model wrongly calculate target dimensions: ValueError: Error when checking target

Tags: python, numpy, keras, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to build a multi-output keras model starting from a working single output model. Keras however, is complaining about tensors dimensions.

**The single output Model:**

This GRU model is training and predicting fine:

```py
timesteps = 250
features = 2

input_tensor = Input(shape=(timesteps, features), name="input")
conv = Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=6,use_bias=True)(input_tensor)
b = BatchNormalization()(conv)
s_gru, states = GRU(256, return_sequences=True, return_state=True, name="gru_1")(b)
biases = keras.initializers.Constant(value=88.15)
out = Dense(1, activation='linear', name="output")(s_gru)
model = Model(inputs=input_tensor, outputs=out)
```

My numpy arrays are:

```py
train_x # shape:(7110, 250, 2) 
train_y # shape: (7110, 250, 1)
```

If fit the model with the following code and everything is fine:

```py
model.fit(train_x, train_y,batch_size=128, epochs=10, verbose=1)
```

**The Problem:**

I want to use a slightly modified version of the network that outputs also the GRU states:

```py
input_tensor = Input(shape=(timesteps, features), name="input")
conv = Conv1D(filters=128, kernel_size=6,use_bias=True)(input_tensor)
b = BatchNormalization()(conv)
s_gru, states = GRU(256, return_sequences=True, return_state=True, name="gru_1")(b)
biases = keras.initializers.Constant(value=88.15)
out = Dense(1, activation='linear', name="output")(s_gru)
model = Model(inputs=input_tensor, outputs=[out, states]) # multi output

#fit the model but with a list of numpy array as y
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mae', loss_weights=[0.5, 0.5])
history = model.fit(train_x, [train_y,train_y], batch_size=128, epochs=10, callbacks=[])
```

This training fails and keras is complaining about the target dimensions:

```py
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected gru_1 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (7110, 250, 1)
```

I'm using Keras 2.3.0 and Tensorflow 2.0.

What am I missing here?

Comment: The dimension of 'states' would be of shape `(7110, 256)` for the number of examples and number of units, and so you can't really compare that to the output of a single `Dense` Unit.

Comment: Thanks! But I'm not connecting the states to the Dense layer. I'm using only `s_gru` as input of the Dense layer. `s_gru` being the output sequences

Comment: Agreed, but nevertheless, the shape of the output you're expecting should match the dimensions of the state. In this example, any np.array of shape `(None, 256)` would do. The case with a single output works because `train_y` has the same sequence length as the input. Could you add the output of `model.summary` for the multi-output case?

Comment: Sorry, I've initially misunderstood your answer. Now I see your point, and by changing the dimensions of the secod array in the target list i can train the network. Thanks! If you want to answer the question, I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dimensions of the second output and the second element in the `outputs` list should be of similar shape. In this case, `states` would be of shape `(7110, 256)`, which can't really be compared to the `train_y` shape (which will be of shape `(7110, 250, 1)` as noted in the first code block. Make sure the outputs can be compared with a similar shape.